# How to check if application runs on the command line?

Tags: java, console

I would like to write a Java application that opens a GUI if started from a GUI and parses command line arguments if started from the command line.

Is there any way to check if the application was started from the GUI?

Comment: What do you mean by "started from the GUI"? Do you mean by double-clicked jar icon in OS?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, that is what I meant by GUI.

Comment: In other words: "executed with the `javaw` command"

Comment: What BinkanSalaryman said. I can also use `javaw YourApp foo bar` from console and because of `javaw`, `System.console()` will be `null` (since `w` at the and stands for `windowed`) but `String[] args` will contain `[foo, bar]`. So despite that I started this app from command via `javaw` my arguments should be ignored or not?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. See edited answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `console()` method of the `System` class returns a `Console` object if a console device is present, otherwise it returns `null`. The expression `args.length > 0` checks if the String array `args` has any elements.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Console console = System.console();
   if (console != null || args.length > 0) {
    // The app was started from a terminal
   }
 }
```